# USB relay commands

Tags: usb, hid

I have this USB Relay:
http://www.ebay.com/itm/5V-USB-Relay-2-Channel-Programmable-Computer-Control-For-Smart-Home-/141097843081?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item20da163989
Al I need is to send close/open  to the device (to turn on & off an LED light)

How can I do that using C# or C++?

Thanks
Boaz

Comment: According to the info on the eBay listing they supply a library that you can use with C/C++.

Comment: You can use `libusbrelaymodule` from https://github.com/nkh-lab/usb-relay-module or `setrelay` CLI app from this project as well. This project supports both Linux and Windows.

Answer (score 2):

Here's what you need (tested on Linux) :

- HIDAPI from http://www.signal11.us/oss/hidapi/
- USBRELAY from https://github.com/darrylb123/usbrelay/blob/master/README.md

Use it like :

- usbrelay ZG4HU_1=1
- usbrelay ZG4HU_1=0

to switch the first relay on and off. ZG4HU_2 addresses the second relay and without arguments you even get the relay status.

-- Hans

Comment: A couple more comments because I've been playing with it today: (1) I think the ID  (ZG4HU in post above) is specific to your device.  (2) The HIDAPI library is in the package libhidapi-dev on Ubuntu.

Answer (score -2):

The 26484  26483.rar is what I needed for Windows. .exe files for graphic and for command line for testing and .dll for my own development.
 Found here: http://files.elektroda.net/794975,26484++26483+usbrelayextlib.html