# Manage relay control through USB within a smart home setup

Tags: java, android, usb, hid

I am working on a smart home system in Android that controls electronic devices.
For my Android project, I've utilized what I believe to be the USB relay board ([USB Relay 2 Channel](https://www.ebay.com/itm/273207402810?hash=item3f9c6e213a:g:%7EtkAAOSwojBdbkIm&amdata=enc%3AAQAIAAABIDZkBo4mqYvUWNggICFbC0qqhbVc4GmPhba%2B4kMwFnwL71yn2q%2FkO1JdXIC1Ym4VSBChezwq5RhTCHKbyyxK8dwfrPurF8Z3j0%2Bolx0UMaROxSWvmT9d0%2FYJK5Ync5cciMjmKmJtiCMrnRfvKugOYB33vlffe1WXi8gVz4uWtQPJpaKPryn8LCVASEmuztuIgm0ogceRRW2ov5SiZiGJhoaO6MFIYPs5vIO4H686KP7nZXHb%2BPCUvYbtNaRROT8cTYoKlIqak1mEWYTLG%2BTv6le5onuInGyG%2FApuT2XXuZz3%2FWC9UnChCQxSNik86Yc5DkJDHYCcCKa4P7B6BbDiXXdgBjFh%2BWrtn%2FbQSSvw6cmAoMUvkmFPoLWu%2F69R5lIRKA%3D%3D%7Ctkp%3ABk9SR_qpu4LIYg) ) to manage various purifiers. These purifiers are connected to several Android devices, all integrated into my smart home system.
I got help on how to communicate with this board from this post : [POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33364402/control-relay-over-usb-from-android)

However, I've come across an unusual issue. Every few days, the relay stops responding to the commands I send. To address this problem, I've attempted the following troubleshooting steps:

1. Closing and reopening the app.
2. Switching to different Android devices.
3. Trying different relay boards.

Unfortunately, none of these steps have proven effective. The only actions that have resolved the issue are rebooting the Android device or disconnecting and reconnecting the relay board.

I'm eager to know if anyone else has encountered this particular bug. Is there a restart command for this board that could potentially "wake it up"?

I've included the code snippet below, which I use to set the relay state within my project:

```
private int setRelay(E_RELAY_NUMBER_TYPES relayChannel, boolean state, int retries) throws IOException {
    int status;
    do {
        byte channelValue = relayChannel == E_RELAY_NUMBER_TYPES.CHANNEL_1 ? (byte) 0x01 : (byte) 0x02;
        if (state) {
            byte[] openRelayBuffer = {(byte) 0xff, channelValue, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00};
            status = deviceConnection.controlTransfer(0x21, 0x09, 0x0300, 0x00, openRelayBuffer, openRelayBuffer.length, 500);
        } else {
            byte[] closeRelayBuffer = {(byte) 0xfd, channelValue, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00};
            status = deviceConnection.controlTransfer(0x21, 0x01, 0x0300, 0x00, closeRelayBuffer, closeRelayBuffer.length, 500);
        }
    } while ((status < 0) && connect() && retries++ < 5);
    return status;
}
```